# Page scrolls to top before navigating to another page using jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

My app has 2 views, list and detail. The list has some 30 items. I have scrolled to the bottom and clicked on an item. It then navigates to the detail view.

Now the issue is that - the list view first is auto-scrolling to the top of the list view (in a snap) and then navigating to the detail view. This ain't desired. I don't want to see that auto-scroll thing.

Am using jQuery and jQuerymobile. Am using jQueryMobile's changePage() function to navigate to another screen.

I tried digging around, but in vain.

Any thoughts would be really helpful

Comment: What you described is the default(and only) behaviour of jquery mobile model...